# PHP: How to call parent method from a trait method used in current class?

Tags: php, inheritance, traits

Let we have following classes:

```
class baseClass {
    function method() {
        echo 'A';
    }
}

trait mixin {
    function mixinFunction() {
        ... /// <-- problem here
    }
}

class currentClass {
    use mixin;

    function method() {
        mixinFunction();
    }
}
...
$object = new currentClass();
$object->method();
```

Is it possible to execute `baseClass::method()` from trait to echo 'A' when calling `$object->method();` without changing this class/method structure and without calling non-static method as static?

**EDIT:**

This was stupid question, the answer is to use `parent::method()` in trait method and it will call `baseClass::method()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The all method from trait `copy` to class, and you must call to methods as `->` or `::`.

```
trait mixin {
    function mixinFunction() {
        ... /// <-- problem here
    }
}

class currentClass {
    use mixin;

    function method() {
        $this->mixinFunction();
    }
}
...
$object = new currentClass();
$object->method();
```

Comment: You are right, this was a stupid question from me :) I need to use `parent::method()` in my trait. By my mistake it didn't work at me when I asked this question :) People says "correct question is more than half of the answer" and this is my case :)

Answer (score 2):

Change it to:

```
class baseClass {
    function method() {
        echo 'A';
    }
}

trait mixin {
    abstract function method();

    function mixinFunction() {
        $this->method();
    }
}

class currentClass extends baseClass {
    use mixin;

    function method() {
        $this->mixinFunction();
    }
}
```